# MaterialBanner is showing above SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

I want to use `MaterialBanner` with `SliverAppBar` and wanted it to be displayed below the SliverAppBar like this: [Banners - Material Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heL56.png).

It is working fine with `AppBar` However, with `SliverAppBar`, it is displaying above the SliverAppBar. Is there a way to display it without placing it inside the Scaffold body?

You can run the DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2fb141d5bbca63d177cecf45543c4419).

Comment: why not inside the scaffold body?

Comment: placing `MaterialBanner` inside the body will lose it's ability to be pinned on top

Comment: If you see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialBanner-class.html)  ```MaterialBanner``` is placed inside the body and working fine.

Comment: yup, placing in the body works fine but I am trying to achieve [this](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/5ae335da176da4b26bce49dd228cc0345dd7a0f9f3a3ccf0069562a249692c3ac0dead206897b2f35a45d558e6aba484b5c9236e1c7a5680a921f9b9d6e4c022)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this behaviour is a recorded on-going issue.

Here's the issue I've created:
[MaterialBanner appears above SliverAppBar](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96216#event-5858224252)

and here's the related issue:
[MaterialBanner updates](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60024)